# Вопрос о причастии "раскрашиваемую"

Tags: орфография, словообразование, причастия

Есть ли такое причастие "раскрашиваемую"?
Ведь оно в настоящем времени и образованно от глагола совершенного вида.
Спрашиваю, т. к. увидел это слово в тексте.

Comment: "Раскрашивать" - глагол _несовершенного_ вида (в отличие от "раскрасить" ->  раскрашенный, раскрасивший).

Comment: Почему это комментарий, а не ответ?

Answer (score 1):

[**раскра́шивать**](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C)
Глагол, несовершенный вид, переходный (соотв. глагол сов. вида — раскрасить).

[**раскра́шиваемый**](http://www.morfologija.ru/%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0/%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83%D1%8E)
Страд. прич. наст. вр. (от раскрашивать).
[Раскрашиваемую – ж. р., В. п., ед. ч.]

Роспись на стенах:
*дополнительные инструменты и материалы включают в себя (...) копировальную бумагу (черную, белую) — для нанесения трафаретов на **раскрашиваемую** поверхность...*

*— Вы расстроены? — спросила Полина, кладя кисть прямо на **раскрашиваемый**

веер.*
Оноре де Бальзак. Шагреневая кожа

*И по вечерам, когда здесь бывало полно народу, и в рабочие будни, когда на берегах можно было увидеть разве что приезжих, детей да художников, для которых все дни — белые полотна, **раскрашиваемые** их фантазиями.*
О. Рой. Паутина лжи

Answer (score 0):

Раскрашивать - глагол несовершенного вида, переходной. Следовательно *раскрашиваемый* при наличии пояснительного слова в творительном падеже будет причастием.

в остальных случаях - прилагательным, так как:

Слова на -МЫЙ, образованные от переходных глаголов несовершенного вида, являются причастиями  при наличии пояснительного слова в творительном падеже (творительного действующего лица или творительного орудия).

При других формах пояснительных слов или без пояснительных слов слова на -МЫЙ переходят в прилагательные (теряют значение страдательности, значение времени и приобретают качественное значение).

Поскольку в вашем случае слово *раскрашиваемый* образовано от глагола *раскрашивать* (переходного, несовершенного вида), то к нему применимо это правило и оно может быть и причастием, и прилагательным:

раскрашиваемые рисунки, отнюдь не раскрашиваемые рисунки, никем не раскрашиваемые рисунки, вовремя нераскрашиваемые рисунки- прилагательное

не раскрашиваемые мальчиком рисунки - причастие.